# Use Outlook Desktop without EWS, IMAP or RPC over HTTP

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access, exchange-2013

My organization runs an Exchange 2013 server with OWA and ActiveSync enabled, however they have recently disabled email access via EWS, IMAP and RPC over HTTP (they would not give a reason as to why, and have indicated no plans to re-enable them).

As a result, I can no longer log in to my emails on the Outlook app on my PC, I can only access them via the Outlook Web App.

I *can* access my emails via Exchange ActiveSync on my iPhone, however when I try to do the same on my PC via this method:

[image]

it fails. Any other method Outlook provides also fails when I try to add my organisation email.

I was able to verify that ActiveSync was enabled and working on the server using the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyser](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Eas/input):

[image]

But any [Outlook Connectivity](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Ola/input) tests I run always fail.

I have tried every possible way I can think of to get my account working on Outlook again, as it was working completely fine up until they made changes to the service.

Currently, I'm just using Thunderbird with the Owl addon to retrieve my mail via OWA, which works fine, but I much prefer Outlook for my work because of its integration with other Office apps, and Thunderbird is also cluttered with my other personal email accounts.

Is there anything else I can try to get my email working on Outlook again? ActiveSync does not appear to be working properly, and I find it weird that it isn't able to connect via OWA like Thunderbird.

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a regular exchange account?

Comment: @JW0914 Yep, that also fails.

Comment: Something seems misconfigured on the server side then, as Hotmail.com/Outlook.com uses AcriveSync and you can still add the account as a normal exchange account _(you simply don't gain the options a normal exchange account offers, such as a `.pst` instead of an `.ost`, making it pointless to do so)_.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Outlook doesn't support connections to a server that's running Exchange Server by using the EAS protocol. It's suggested that you could connect to Exchange by using the standard Exchange connection settings.

[image]

For more information, please refer to: [Outlook doesn't support connections to Exchange by using ActiveSync and error: Log onto Exchange ActiveSync mail server (EAS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/outlook-cannot-use-activesync-connect-exchange).

Comment: I've also tried this before, and still no success.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you mentioned at the beginning that your administrator has disabled email access via EWS, IMAP and RPC over HTTP. Because of this, I'm afraid you can't access your account on the Outlook desktop client and you can only access it through OWA:(